# React-Leaflet - Custom Pin, OnClick Link to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a react-leaflet integration with custom pins (Via divIcon)

```
const divIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: '',
      html: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <CustomPin pinColour={pinColour} pinCode={pinCode} pinID={id} history={history} />
      ),
      iconSize: [24, 40],
      iconAnchor: [12, 40],
      popupAnchor: [0, -40]
});
```

If I want to do a redirect when the user clicks the custom icon, how can I do this?

Including a  tag in the ReactDOMServer.renderToString is obviously not possible.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You would like to click the marker and redirect to another page. Is that correct?

Comment: @kboul That's correct

Comment: Hi @LiamB. Did you check my answer. Did it solve your issue?

Comment: Yea, perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define two routes on index.js:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={MapLeaflet} />
      <Route path="/another-page" component={AnotherPage} />
    </Router>
  );
};
```

MapLeaflet will be the component which will contain your map and AnotherPage for instance another component that you will be redirected to after clicking the marker.

Then in your MapLeaflet comp

```
<Marker
    position={position}
    icon={customMarker}
    onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/another-page")}>
```

use `onClick` event to navigate to another-page route from the `Marker`

I have included optionally the possibility to navigate back to '/' route from AnotherPage comp.

Also I used  `L.icon` instead of `L.divIcon`. Hopefully it is ok for you.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/8227p6462)